# Pivot-table in pandas: aggfunc sum during date range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe like the following:

```
#               Date      Name  RG
#-----------------------------------
#      1: 2013-04-25     NameA   1
#      2: 2013-04-25     NameB   3
#      3: 2013-04-25     NameC   1
#      4: 2013-04-25     NameD   2
#      5: 2013-04-25     NameE   1
#     ---                                                                              
#  13379: 2020-02-13     NameA   3
#  13380: 2020-02-13     NameB   1
#  13381: 2020-02-13     NameC   4
#  13382: 2020-02-13     NameD   1
#  13383: 2020-02-13     NameE   1
```

I want to pivot the table and use **Name** column as index. Each **Date** appears now as an individual column, so that, for each **Name** index, **RG** is summed during the past six months, e.g., RG value for NameA in 2020-02-06 is obtained by adding all RG values for NameA between 2019-08-07 and 2020-02-06. For example:

```
#          Name     2013-04-25      2013-04-31      2013-05-07   ---   2020-02-06      2020-02-13
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#      1: NameA     1               2               3                  7               23
#      2: NameB     3               3               6                  15              21
#      3: NameC     1               4               5                  16              24
#      4: NameD     2               2               7                  19              40
#      5: NameE     1               4               9                  15              21
#     ---                                                                              
#    276: NameDE    3               4               6                  15              22
#    277: NameDF    1               4               6                  17              22
#    278: NameDG    4               8               9                  11              23
#    279: NameDH    2               3               5                  19              24
#    280: NameDI    1               4               6                  18              20
```

I could pivot the table by using the following:

```
df.pivot_table(
    values='RG', index='Name', columns='Date',
    fill_value=0, aggfunc='sum')
```

However, values in each column should be the cumulative sum of all values during the previous six months for the same **Name**. How can I modify aggfunc to accomplish such goal?

Comment: Use `'cumsum'` instead of `'sum'` as `aggfunc`?

Comment: That does not solve the problem. I want to get the cumulative sum for the six months prior to each date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Before pivoting, it is necessary to generate the cumsum for the selected period by following procedure:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    currentDate = row['Date']
    previousDate = row['Date'] - pd.DateOffset(months=12)
    name = row['Name']
    mask = (df['Date'] > previousDate) & (df['Date'] <= currentDate) & (df['Name'] == name)
    s = df.loc[mask]['RG'].sum()
    df4.loc[index,'RG'] = s
```